# Change my view: The UK probably won't grant full UK citizenship to Hong Kongers with BN(O) passports

Tags: discussion

Are posts in the format of r/changemyview posts allowed? If they are, please help me clarify [Change my view: The UK probably won't grant full UK citizenship to Hong Kongers with BN(O) passports](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/44182/27464)? Thx.

Answer (score 11):

Answering as I was the first close-voter. :)

I believe that the CMV format (as well as [ELI5](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/) and many others) is **an invitation to an open-ended debate**. There is no criteria like "Okay, at this point the question is fully answered". There is neither way to judge whether a certain answer actually answers the question. It's like "what is your favorite food?" — everyone has their opinion, and their own arguments *why*, but there is no answer to this question.

In addition, "Here's my opinion, change my view" can be seen as a non-question that only exists to promote or discredit this view in disguise.

Some would also say that changing someone's view is never our goal. We ask for and find factual information on various topics, and it's everyone's decision whether to keep their views intact or change it.

It's not good and not bad; Stack Exchange is not a bullettin board killer, people like different formats, and every community sets its own rules and accepted formats. Stack Exchange is designed as a Question and Answer site with highest possible signal-to-noise ratio, this is the way how it is.

You can re-phrase your post to make it actually asking an answerable question, and it will get re-opened.
Keep in mind that if you have several distinct questions, it is better to ask them separately, perhaps with links to each other for context.

Comment: FYI, since you mentioned ELI5: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/can-somebody-explain-brexit-in-a-few-child-proof-sentences

Comment: @Fizz, good point. I recall discussions on Area 51 (or Meta.SE?) about the creation of ELI5.SE, especially after the success of [skeptics.se].